# Reducing the complexity of a turing machine algorithm

Tags: computability

i'm trying to solve this question:
Given a turing machine that is decidable by at most 50 * n^4 steps, can we build a dif algorithm that can decide it in n^4 steps?

Me and my friends thought about it, and we coulnd't get it right.
Some points we had in mind:
1. if you can reduce the overall cost by 50 somehow, couldn't you reduce it over and over again?
2. we tried to think about algorithms that require 50*n^4 moves (at most) and we thought about this language: string str is in A if str.GetHashCode().GetHashCode()... 50 times is even. do you think this algorithm is unreducable?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Why did you down vote it? Its a pretty hard question..

Comment: It's not a good idea for the body of your question to be exactly the same as the title.  It really makes it look like you haven't put in much effort to formulate a good question.  Add to that the fact that this is obviously homework, and a lot of people are going to assume you copied it directly from your assignment.  Put in some effort and show us what you've come up with on your own.

Comment: ok, i'll rewrite it

Comment: better? i really thought about it for a long time.. really non trivial one.

Comment: Your edit increased the quality of the question by at least 50 times.  ;)

Comment: thanks. Now i hope i could talk with someone about it and understand how to answer it :)

Comment: Now that it's improved, I'm going to migrate it over to the [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site where it belongs.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, this is not research level question. Check [the speedup theorem on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup_theorem). Please do not migrate this kind of questions directly to cstheory, migrate them first to [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). cstheory is for *research level* questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaveh: Sorry about that.  I forgot to read the FAQ before migrating.  Thanks for the link, though.  That should answer his question.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, no problem. :)

Comment: @Adibe7, I think [the wiki page for linear speed-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_speedup_theorem) should answer your question, but if you want I can remigrate the question to Math.SE from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_speedup_theorem). If you don't want to look it up, think how can you build a TM then executes $50$ steps of the old machine at once; you may need some bootstrapping phase.